# Azure Storage Queue like on premise

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I know this question is ambigus but I could find anything relevant.

Is there any software, nuggget, role in SQL, role in Windows Server, or whatever that works like the Azure Queues?

I have a cloud web site running on azure that store some message in an Azure queue. A background service (Azure Web Job) is monitoring the queue, and when there is a new message it is processed on background. I would like to do something like this on premise.

What should I do for create a queue and monitor it from a Windows Service, like in Azure?

Comment: MSMQ on a Windows box. Libraries like NServiceBus place a layer over the top of MSMQ and give you much more fantastical operations over it. Definitely look into MSMQ and NServiceBus (don't do what we have done and write your own custom wrapper around MSMQ - its stupid when NServiceBus is so good. Just pay for it! /rant).

Comment: Another option is Service Bus for Windows Server (though I admit I haven't looked too deeply at this): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282144.aspx

Comment: Why not continuing to use Azure Queues?  You can just as easily use Azure Queues from on premises applications.

Comment: Because this is going to be sell as a software product to third parties. We dont want to say the clients that they have to buy Azure to can use it.

Comment: Service Bus for Windows Server is the closest.  But, there's other message queues out there too, like RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for feature parity and want to switch between Azure and on-premise; Service Bus for Windows Server does exactly what you are looking for. This is an on-premise installation of the same features offered in the Azure cloud.

[Service Bus for Windows Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282144.aspx)

> The purpose of Service Bus for Windows Server is to provide similar capabilities across Windows Azure and Windows Server, and to enable flexibility in developing and deploying applications. It is built on the same architecture as the Service Bus cloud service and provides scale and resiliency capabilities. The programming model, Visual Studio support, and APIs exposed for developing applications are symmetric to that for the cloud service making it easier to develop applications for either, and switch between the two.
> [Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1 Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282142.aspx)

If it's just queue's you are looking for you could also work with MSMQ, which can be installed as a Windows feature.

[Installing Message Queuing (MSMQ)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967729(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Message Queuing (MSMQ) technology enables applications running at different times to communicate across heterogeneous networks and systems that may be temporarily offline. Applications send messages to queues and read messages from queues. [Message Queuing (MSMQ)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx)

There are more alternatives for message queue's but these are either already available on your Windows environment or have feature parity with Azure.